# Problems with borders

Tags: html, css, hover

I have one problem with my border. The problem is that I have 2 different borders: one that is on the "DUCO" button (my name) and one that creates itself when you hover over the text. The problem is that that the borders aren't the same size. can anyone help? (you cant see the background but that is no big deal)

Thanks

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

header
{
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(straat.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.hoofd-nav
{
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
    
.hoofd-nav li
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.hoofd-nav li a
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.hoofd-nav li.actief
{
    border: 3px solid white;
}

.hoofd-nav li a:hover
{
    border: 3px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title> Duco's Blog </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
    
<body> 
    <header>
        <div class="rij">
        <ul class="hoofd-nav">
            <li class="actief"><a href=""> Duco </a></li>
            <li><a href=""> Hobbys </a></li>
            <li><a href=""> Dromen </a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to decide: border on `a` or `li`. Don't scramble both

Comment: If any of the answers help you, you should mark it as the answer. This will help other users as well.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to set the `.active` class on the `a` tag.Then you can also set a `transparent` border to remove the wobble.

The problem is comming from the mixing of both `a` and `li` tags. So the example is for the `a` tag but might as well be the `li` tag.

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

header
{
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(straat.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.hoofd-nav
{
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
    
.hoofd-nav li
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.hoofd-nav li a
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 3px solid transparent; /* Remove wobble */
}
.hoofd-nav li a.actief
{
    border: 3px solid white;
}

.hoofd-nav li a:hover
{
    border: 3px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title> Duco's Blog </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
    
<body> 
    <header>
        <div class="rij">
        <ul class="hoofd-nav">
            <li><a href="" class="actief"> Duco </a></li>
            <li><a href=""> Hobbys </a></li>
            <li><a href=""> Dromen </a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your static border (the one on "DUCO") and the other border (the one that appears when hovering over "DUCO") are not borders of the same element!

The static one is a border for the `li` while the other one is applied on the `a` tag inside the `li`.

Try making both border properties applied on the same element, and it should work fine.